# Por qué GitHub Pages me muestra el readme

Tags: github-pages

este es mi repositorio https://github.com/Aleja184/e-commerce tiene el archivo index.html dentro de la carpeta html. Cuando lo subo a GitHub Pages solo me aparece el readme. Intenté sacando mi index.html de la carpeta, pero no me funcionó.¿Cómo lo puedo arreglar?

Comment: Accediendo a https://aleja184.github.io/e-commerce/html/ sí que se ve, por tanto entiendo que es un problema con la estructura de carpetas del sitio. Todo lo que tienes en la carpeta html debería estar en el raiz y seguramente tengas que cambiar rutas en las urls de los htmls

Answer (score 0):

Intenta **cambiar el nombre** de tu archivo **HTML** a "index.html", después haz un ligero cambio en tu index.html y hazle commit.

Si lo sacaste de la carpeta, solo haz el cambio y comitealo, no te olvides de eso.